# Fourier Transform of Exponentiated Cosine

Tags: integration, fourier-transform, periodic-functions

So I've spent the last few hours going around in circles trying to solve this. I have this equation:

$e^{(\cos{t})-1}$

of which I am trying to obtain the Fourier Transform for. What I have tried is start from the following (from the definition of the FT)

$F({\omega}) = \int e^{(\cos{t})-1} e^{-i\omega t} dt =  \frac{1}{e}\int e^{(\cos{t})} e^{-i\omega t} dt $

I tried

1. using the identity $cos(At) = \frac{e^{iAt}+e^{-iAt}}{2}$

which results in an exponential of an exponential of complex numbers. I couldn't get any further from here and none of my FT tables give anything for this kind of form

2. Following a method similar to the derivation of the FT of the Gaussian function by using integration by parts (page 4 of this pdf http://code.ucsd.edu/zeger/45/Gaussian.pdf )
3. Following the method of the last page of that pdf and splitting the Fourier $e^{-i\omega t}$ term into separate cosine and sin function and then use the Taylor expansion of cos but this still leaves the $e^{(\cos{t})}$ term. Perhaps *that* cosine term could be also split into an expansion however that looks like it could be messy.
4. Integration by substitution for the top function but this led nowhere.

I have also attempted to put this into Mathematica but itdoes not solve it and simply returns the input. My suspicion is this has something to do with the infinite integral.

If anyone could offer some advice on how to proceed it would be greatly appreciated!

regards

Comment: The integral does not converge in any of (1) improper integral sense, (2) Lebesgue integral sense, (3) $L^2(\Bbb{R})$. This may admit a Fourier transform in distribution sense and the transform will probably consist of point masses, but I am not sure if this is what you want.

Comment: @SangchulLee hey, thanks for the reply. I read in passing a little about using distributions from the FT as opposed a sum from the Fourier Series. I would definitely be interested in translating the problem in this sense.

Answer (score 3):

Since $e^{\cos(t)}$ is periodic, what you want is a Fourier series, not Fourier transform.

$$ \int_0^{2\pi} e^{\cos(t)-1} \exp(i k t)\; dt = 2 \pi I_k(1)/e$$ where $I_k$ is a modified Bessel function of order $k$.

Comment: thanks @RobertIsrael This makes sense! Could you provide a reference that shows how to arrive at that result?

Comment: See [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html) formula (5).

Comment: I went over it again and could arrive at that result; thanks. To confirm is it simply just equation (5) multiplied by 2? If instead it was cos(wt), would one then have to transform equation (5) somehow to accommodate? Finally, The answer you gave is evaluated between [0,2pi] however the Fourier Series would have to be evaluated from [-inf, inf]; how would you go about doing that? Would it be some kind of convolution with an impulse train and if so would there be some kind of scale factor?

Comment: The Fourier series coefficients for a periodic function with period $T$ are found using an integral over an interval of length $T$.

Comment: Managed to work it out in the end! Thanks Robert